# -contains return false instead of true

Tags: powershell

I tried this

```psh
$arrColors = import-csv -header color colors.txt
$arrColors -contains "blue"
```

Where colors.txt contains

```
blue
red
green
```

Result is false instead of true why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$arrColors.color -contains "blue"
```

In powershell version before 3.0 this not works but you can do it like this:

```
($arrColors | select -expand color) -contains "blue"
```

Thank to @Matt to point this out

Comment: This is dependant on PowerShell version to work. Think you need 3.0 at least

Comment: I didnt want to add an answer just for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Obtain the `color` property on the CSV object:

```
$arrColors = (import-csv colors.txt).color
$arrColors -contains "blue"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the type of $arrColors, you will see it is a table.
You cannot compare a table and a string.

What you can do is to check if there is a blue in the table :

```
    PS> $arrColors|Where-object{$_.color -eq 'blue}
```

then you have to count the lines in output, which gives us the following :

```
    PS> $arrColors|Where-object{$_.color -eq 'blue'}| Measure-Object
```

and check if this positive

```
    PS> $counter=$arrColors|Where-object{$_.color -eq 'blue'}| Measure-Object -property color
    PS> $counter.color -gt 0
```

Comment: It is not a "table" really but an object array with a color property.

Comment: Ok but let's be intuitive: .... select and where are more intuitive if you think of a table ...  but it's true from a syntact point of view: it's a System.Array object

Comment: @BrunoC short way: `[bool]($arrColors | ? {$_.color -eq 'blue' })`

Comment: @CB. Less pedagogic but  ... Excellent!